# Manage windows inside a panel with a 'Windows'-like menu

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I've a panel.

I add WinForms inside it. The WinForms added have the TopLevel and Visible properties set to FALSE and TRUE.

I can do a `panel.SetChildIndex(WinForm1,0)` to bring WinForm1 to front.

What I've not managed to do is keep a track of the actual `ChildIndex` of the panel.

The idea is to have buttons that opens forms inside the panel, and that when the panel opens a new button is added in a `Windows` menu.

Something like when many files are open on a VS Project, you can go to Window menu and select one. Also, if you change the active page by clicking the page, the Window menu auto-updates and checks the actual active page.

I want to do this, but with a panel container. I've managed to get done everithing, but not the `the Window menu auto-updates and checks the actual active page` part.

Isn't there an event fired when `BringToFront()` or `SetChildIndex(form, index)` are called? Any event when I click another form that's inside the panel and it becomes the "active one"? Or some property of the panel that I can keep track of that changes when active form changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that when a form inside a panel is closed, the `Controls` property of the panel gets reindexed, where the index zero is the form that gets the new focus. Now that I've a way to check the form that's in front when I close another one, windows administration in panels is done.

Going to put the source code, maybe it can help someone :)

Please note that I'm using a RadRibbonForm, a standard panel, and RadForms inside the panel. Rad's are from Telerik. Some things should change to make this work on standardWinForms, but the changes are minimal.

Also, I'm not using a menu that shows the forms, I'm using RadButtonElement's in a page of the ribbon menu instead.

`AddRadFormWindow` must be called to put a window and manage it automatically.

Example of adding a window:

`AddRadFormWindow(typeof (MyRadForm))`

Now, the source. It must be inside the code of the RadRibbonForm's class.

```
public static class ExtensionsRadForm
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg);

    public static void Deminimize(this RadForm form)
    {
        if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            ShowWindow(form.Handle, 9);
    }
}

    private void RefreshButtonsChecks(string windowName)
    {
        if (windowName != null)
        {
            principalPanel.Controls[windowName].BringToFront();
        }
        if (principalPanel.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            if (principalPanel.Controls.Cast<RadForm>().Any(radForm => radForm.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized))
            {
                foreach (RadItem item in radRibbonBarGroupOpenWindows.Items)
                {
                    var buttonBorder = ((RadButtonElement) item).BorderElement;
                    if (item.Name == panelPrincipal.Controls[0].Name + "Button")
                    {
                        buttonBorder.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                        buttonBorder.BottomColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                        buttonBorder.TopColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                        buttonBorder.LeftColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                        buttonBorder.RightColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                        principalPanel.Controls[0].Focus();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        buttonBorder.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
                        buttonBorder.BottomColor = Color.Transparent;
                        buttonBorder.TopColor = Color.Transparent;
                        buttonBorder.LeftColor = Color.Transparent;
                        buttonBorder.RightColor = Color.Transparent;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (RadItem item in radRibbonBarGroupAbiertas.Items)
                {
                    var buttonBorder = ((RadButtonElement)item).BorderElement;
                    buttonBorder.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
                    buttonBorder.BottomColor = Color.Transparent;
                    buttonBorder.TopColor = Color.Transparent;
                    buttonBorder.LeftColor = Color.Transparent;
                    buttonBorder.RightColor = Color.Transparent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
private void PrincipalPanelLayout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshButtonsChecks(null);
    }
private void RadButtonElementCloseAllWindowsClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int limitButtons = radRibbonBarGroupOpenWindows.Items.Count;
        for (int index = 0; index < limitButtons; index++)
        {
            RadItem radItem = radRibbonBarGroupOpenWindows.Items[0];
            radItem.Dispose();
        }
        int limitControls = principalPanel.Controls.Count;
        for (int index = 0; index < limitControls; index++)
        {
            Control control = principalPanel.Controls[0];
            control.Dispose();
        }
        Update();
        GC.Collect();
    }
private void AddRadFormWindow(Type windowToAdd)
    {
        if (!principalPanel.Controls.ContainsKey(windowToAdd.Name))
        {
            var window = (RadForm) Activator.CreateInstance(windowToAdd);
            window.TopLevel = false;
            window.Visible = true;
            window.FormClosing += (method, args) =>
                                       {
                                           radRibbonBarGroupOpenWindows.Items[window.Name + "Button"].Dispose();
                                           GC.Collect();
                                       };
            window.Enter += (method, args) => RefreshButtonsChecks(window.Name);
            var closeMenuItem = new RadMenuItem("Close");
            closeMenuItem.MouseDown += (method, args) =>
                                           {
                                               panelPrincipal.Controls[window.Name].Dispose();
                                               radRibbonBarGroupOpenWindows.Items[window.Name + "Button"].Dispose();
                                           };
            var contextMenu = new RadContextMenu();
            contextMenu.Items.Add(closeMenuItem);
            var button = new RadButtonElement(window.Text) {Name = window.Name + "Button"};
            button.MouseDown += (method, args) =>
                                    {
                                        switch (args.Button)
                                        {
                                            case MouseButtons.Left:
                                                if (((RadForm) principalPanel.Controls[window.Name]).WindowState ==
                                                    FormWindowState.Minimized)
                                                    ((RadForm) principalPanel.Controls[window.Name]).Deminimize();
                                                principalPanel.Controls[window.Name].BringToFront();
                                                principalPanel.Controls[window.Name].Focus();
                                                break;
                                            case MouseButtons.Right:
                                                contextMenu.Show(MousePosition);
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    };
            radRibbonBarGroupOpenWindows.Items.Add(button);
            principalPanel.Controls.Add(window);
            principalPanel.Controls[window.Name].BringToFront();
            principalPanel.Controls[window.Name].Focus();
        }
        principalPanel.Controls[windowToAdd.Name].BringToFront();
        principalPanel.Controls[windowToAdd.Name].Focus();
        Update();
        GC.Collect();
    }
public Constructor()
    {
        panelPrincipal.Layout += PanelPrincipalLayout;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d24477dc-fe11-48ab-8b33-532848f7c3d8/)

> When Control's ZOrder is chaged layout operation is always performed
>   in control's container control.
>
> When I subscribed to container's Layout event and called
>   BringToFront() it showed me Control that changed its
>   ZOrder(LayoutEventArgs.AffectedControl) and changed property
>   (LayoutEventArgs.AffectedProperty).

Comment: Just more than useful. Stil, there is one big problem... What if I `Close` the form? `AffectedControl` doesn't give me the actual form that's going to be in front. And I can't find the way to get the actual form in the front of the `panel`. Just that is getting me away from perfection xD!

Comment: @mishamosher: I would suggest you break your problems in different meaningful questions and ask them one by one on SO. Here your question was Isn't there an event fired when BringToFront() or SetChildIndex(form, index) are called? and here you got the answer. I think this question has completed here.

Comment: Here are `many` questions, not just that. Going to make the non-answered ones on another threads. Thanks for the `Layout` tip, it's great!

Comment: Didn't asked. Found a solution, a complete one. Own answer posted